# Xamarin Studio: How to prevent Xamarin Studio to unhide my code

Tags: android, xamarin, ide, setting

I have a problem with the Xamarin Studio IDE. Whenever I have #region or hiding the statements in the method, it unhided it everytime I open the Xamarin Studio.

How do I prevent it from doing that... I want to keep it tidy everytime I open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows, go to the Tools menu, then Options, then under TextEditor section go to General. Ensure you have "Enable code folding" and "Fold #region by default" options turned on. On a Mac, open the Preferences option from the Xamarin Studio menu and follow the same steps. Happy Coding!

[image: Options View]